# how can I make pulseaudio accept connections again

Tags: pulseaudio

In my arch system, only the headphone outputs audio. the notebook speakers are muted.

My first thought was to engage the `pavucontrol` utility, which gets stuck trying to connect to the pulse server.

with further investigation I narrowed down to these commands that seem reproduce the core problem:

```
~ $ pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -D -v
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup successful.
~ $ ps aux |grep pulse
ninrod    7920  0.0  0.0 199388  6904 ?        S<l  11:11   0:00 pulseaudio -D -v
ninrod    7921  0.0  0.0  82768  3556 ?        S    11:11   0:00 /usr/lib/pulse/gconf-helper
ninrod    7945  0.0  0.0  10800  2240 pts/0    S+   11:12   0:00 grep pulse
~ $ pactl info
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
~ $
```

Seems that my pulse server is not allowing connections from `pactl` or any external clients.

What can I do to make it behave again?

edit: here's the output of `pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -vvvv`:

```
$ pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -vvvv
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operação não permitida
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operação não permitida
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 10.0
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -Wall -W -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wuns
afe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclarat
ion-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing
 -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-color=auto                                                       
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 4.11.9-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 5 18:23:08 CEST 2017
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 4 CPUs.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 5f605d1f46a347c1b8e8193eb8d378ed.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is c1.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/ninrod/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-10.0/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: System supports high resolution timers
D: [pulseaudio] memblock.c: Using shared memfd memory pool with 1024 slots of size 64,0 KB each, total size is 64,0 MB, maximum usable slot size is 65472
I: [pulseaudio] cpu-x86.c: CPU flags: CMOV MMX SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] sconv_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized conversions.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_orc.c: Initialising ORC optimized volume functions.
D: [pulseaudio] database-tdb.c: Opened TDB database '/home/ninrod/.config/pulse/5f605d1f46a347c1b8e8193eb8d378ed-device-volumes.tdb'
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/ninrod/.config/pulse/5f605d1f46a347c1b8e8193eb8d378ed-device-volumes'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-device-restore" (index: #0; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] database-tdb.c: Opened TDB database '/home/ninrod/.config/pulse/5f605d1f46a347c1b8e8193eb8d378ed-stream-volumes.tdb'
I: [pulseaudio] module-stream-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/ninrod/.config/pulse/5f605d1f46a347c1b8e8193eb8d378ed-stream-volumes'.
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-dbus.c: Interface org.PulseAudio.Ext.StreamRestore1 added for object /org/pulseaudio/stream_restore1
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-stream-restore" (index: #1; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] database-tdb.c: Opened TDB database '/home/ninrod/.config/pulse/5f605d1f46a347c1b8e8193eb8d378ed-card-database.tdb'
I: [pulseaudio] module-card-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/ninrod/.config/pulse/5f605d1f46a347c1b8e8193eb8d378ed-card-database'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-card-restore" (index: #2; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-augment-properties" (index: #3; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-switch-on-port-available" (index: #4; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib/pulse-10.0/modules/module-udev-detect.so': success
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /dev/snd/controlC0 is accessible: yes
D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0 is busy: yes
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Found 1 cards.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-udev-detect" (index: #5; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib/pulse-10.0/modules/module-jackdbus-detect.so': failure
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib/pulse-10.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so': failure
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib/pulse-10.0/modules/module-bluetooth-discover.so': failure
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib/pulse-10.0/modules/module-esound-protocol-unix.so': success
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-esound-protocol-unix" (index: #6; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib/pulse-10.0/modules/module-gconf.so': success
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-gconf" (index: #7; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-default-device-restore.c: Saved default sink 'auto_null' not existent, not restoring default sink setting.
I: [pulseaudio] module-default-device-restore.c: Saved default source 'auto_null.monitor' not existent, not restoring default source setting.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-default-device-restore" (index: #8; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-rescue-streams" (index: #9; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module-always-sink.c: Autoloading null-sink as no other sinks detected.
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c: Created sink 0 "auto_null" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.description = "Saída fictícia"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.class = "abstract"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-card"
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
I: [pulseaudio] source.c: Created source 0 "auto_null.monitor" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.description = "Monitor of Saída fictícia"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.class = "monitor"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
D: [null-sink] module-null-sink.c: Thread starting up
D: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Could not set format on sink auto_null
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-null-sink" (index: #11; argument: "sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Saída fictícia"'").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-always-sink" (index: #10; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-intended-roles" (index: #12; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Sink auto_null becomes idle, timeout in 5 seconds.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-suspend-on-idle" (index: #13; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib/pulse-10.0/modules/module-console-kit.so': success
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-console-kit" (index: #14; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] module.c: Checking for existence of '/usr/lib/pulse-10.0/modules/module-systemd-login.so': success
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Created 0 "Login Session c1"
D: [pulseaudio] module-systemd-login.c: Added new session c1
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-systemd-login" (index: #15; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-position-event-sounds" (index: #16; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] stream-interaction.c: Using role 'phone' as trigger role.
D: [pulseaudio] stream-interaction.c: Using roles 'music' and 'video' as cork roles.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-role-cork" (index: #17; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-heuristics" (index: #18; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-apply" (index: #19; argument: "").
D: [pulseaudio] dbus-util.c: Successfully connected to D-Bus session bus c86d14444a13fcff6d4aad36596cbfd9 as :1.160
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Got org.PulseAudio1!
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Got org.pulseaudio.Server!
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup complete.
```